# joomla 3 в файл intro_image.php добавить название категории и дату

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Всем **привет**!

У меня есть файл:

```
templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php
```

в него мне нужно вставить код, который бы отображал название категории в которую входит материал чей intro image отображается на сайте + добавить дату публикации этого материала...

Как это сделать - не пойму... Пробовал по-разному:

```
$this->category->text

$this->category->title
```

и еще кучу разного кода типа:

```
$title = $this->escape($displayData['item']->category_title);
```

Ничего не получается...

Кто-то может подсказать как это сделать?

Заранее **благодарю за ответы**!

Comment: материалы выводятся через модуль? или через шаблон блога категории? или как?

Comment: Через шаблон блога:

templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php

Comment: в таком случае вам нужно перегружать другой файл /templates/my_template/com_content/category/blog_item.php

Comment: там уже получается intro_image материала через $var = json_decode($this->item->images), оно будет в $var->intro_image. А название категории, если мне память не изменяет, там выводится так: $this->item->category_title

Comment: помоему даже intro_image там уже изначально доступно в $images->image_intro (но это не точно). В любом случае можете использовать var_dump и все посмотреть что где лежит

Comment: Да, я в курсе этого, но мне нужно перенести название категории и дату публикации материала ИМЕННО в файл templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php

Comment: Все дело в том, что сама категория (ее назавние и ссылка), формируется в файле templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/category.php, а дата публикации в templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php... Но, для того чтобы к ним добраться с того же blog_item там длюннющая строка с проверкой: 

if ($useDefList && ($info == 0 || $info == 2)) :
      echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.block', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'above'));
     endif;

Comment: Просто скопировать код и вставить в intro_image.php - не получается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что все же можно обойтись без запроса к БД...

Достаточно было в

```
templates/my_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block
```

создать 2-а файла:

1) category_title.php, в котором прописать это:

```
   <?php defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
   echo $this->escape($displayData['item']->category_title);
   ?>
```

2) publish_date_no_html.php, в котором прописать это:

```
   <?php defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
   echo JHtml::_('date', $displayData['item']->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'));
   ?>
```

а в blog_item.php добавить:

```
$cat_name = JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.category_title', array('item' => $this->item));
$art_publish_date = JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.publish_date_no_html', array('item' => $this->item));
JRequest::setVar('cat_name', $cat_name, 'post'); //задаем глобальную переменную
JRequest::setVar('art_publish_date', $art_publish_date, 'post'); //задаем глобальную переменную
```

и уже в intro_image.php, добавить это:

```
$cat_name = JRequest::getVar('cat_name', '', 'post'); //считываем глобальную переменную
$art_publish_date = JRequest::getVar('art_publish_date', '', 'post'); //считываем глобальную переменную
```

и в нужном месте, через echo вывести название категории и дату публикации материала...